# Regarding installation of netbeans

Tags: java

I am trying to install netbeans in my laptop, an error message of "All of the available components are already installed".
Although I have uninstalled the netbeans from my laptop.
What should I do to reinstall the netbeans in my laptop

Comment: [Other possible solutions](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=netbeans+All+of+the+available+components+are+already+installed&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=4DV5WuaqG6bu8wfbq5uIDQ)

Comment: Best thing to do when you get an error message, is to Google it

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the Netbeans folder inside the C://Program Files directory.
And then again try installing.